# Where should I configure benchmark outputs in JMH?

Tags: logging, java-17, microbenchmark, jmh

Where do I tell [JMH (Java Microbenchmark Harness)](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh) to output to a log file?

I have a test based on [this `BenchmarkLoop.java` example](https://mkyong.com/java/java-jmh-benchmark-tutorial/) working against an OrientDB backend server and it all runs fine in the console.
But I need to save for the future evaluation and reference over time with the project-code itself.

I can see target is getting generated, but I don't see any logs output there or anywhere else in the project. Nor can I tell [Log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) to take in what JMH outputs.

I've been trying to search for answers myself:

1. [Internet searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=jmh+output&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS1044US1044&oq=jmh+&aqs=chrome.2.69i59l4j69i64j69i65l3.2663j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) only to find stuff like [Understanding JMH Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604084/understanding-jmh-output) which isn't my concern
2. Digging around in SO for [[jmh] output](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjmh%5D+output) returning [JMH: Buggy output in a benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72685247/jmh-buggy-output-in-a-benchmark) at time of this post
3. Sifting through JMH records, docs, and examples

   1. [GitHub](https://github.com/guozheng/jmh-tutorial/blob/master/README.md)
   2. [JavaDocs (Doc)](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.openjdk.jmh/jmh-core/latest/index.html)
   3. [OpenJDK (Doc)](https://openjdk.org/projects/code-tools/jmh/)
   4. [Baeldung (Example)](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness)
   5. [Mkyong (Example)](https://mkyong.com/java/java-jmh-benchmark-tutorial/)
   6. [OpenAI](https://chat.openai.com/) suggestions don't work for my needs

      1. the CLI way of using `-rf` but I need this project packageable
      2. `resultFormat()` is closer but I think is wrong in its expectation

         ```java
         .resultFormat(ResultFormatFactory.getInstance(ResultFormatType.TEXT, new FileWriter("output-file.txt")))
         ```

         1. We can see that it only takes in a `ResultFormatType`

```markdown
87.039 ms/op

Result "jmh.Test51_1.retrieveASubgraphOf1000Elements":
  97.618 ±(99.9%) 31.200 ms/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (87.039, 97.618, 106.949), stdev = 8.102
  CI (99.9%): [66.418, 128.818] (assumes normal distribution)


# Run complete. Total time: 00:01:42

REMEMBER: The numbers below are just data. To gain reusable insights, you need to follow up on
why the numbers are the way they are. Use profilers (see -prof, -lprof), design factorial
experiments, perform baseline and negative tests that provide experimental control, make sure
the benchmarking environment is safe on JVM/OS/HW level, ask for reviews from the domain experts.
Do not assume the numbers tell you what you want them to tell.

Benchmark                                                     (orientdbUrl)  Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
Test51_1.retrieveASubgraphOf1000Elements  remote:localhost:2424/sparse_data  avgt    5  97.618 ± 31.200  ms/op

Process finished with exit code 0
```

```java
package jmh;

import org.apache.commons.configuration2.BaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientGraph;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversal;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Fork(value = 2, jvmArgs = {"-Xms2G", "-Xmx2G"})
public class Test {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);
    @Param("remote:localhost:2424/sparse_data")
    String orientdbUrl;
    Configuration configuration;
    OrientGraph orientGraph;
    static GraphTraversalSource g;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(Test.class.getSimpleName())
                .forks(1)
                .build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        orientdbUrl = "remote:localhost:2424/sparse_data";
        logger.info("{\torientdb.database.url:\t" + orientdbUrl + "\t}");
        configuration = new BaseConfiguration();
        configuration.setProperty(OrientGraph.CONFIG_URL, orientdbUrl);
        configuration.setProperty(OrientGraph.CONFIG_USER, "root");
        configuration.setProperty(OrientGraph.CONFIG_PASS, "rootpwd");
        configuration.setProperty(OrientGraph.CONFIG_TRANSACTIONAL, true);
        orientGraph = OrientGraph.open(configuration);
        g = orientGraph.traversal();
    }
    @TearDown
    public void teardown() {
        orientGraph.close();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public static void retrieveASubgraphOf1000Elements() {
        GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> returnValue = g.V().limit(1000);
        while (returnValue.hasNext()) {
            logger.info("returnValue.next():\t" + returnValue.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [JMH: Returning the benchmark results as a json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071804/jmh-returning-the-benchmark-results-as-a-json-object), where the asker was asking about returning their value. This snippet of theirs was what I needed.

```java
            .resultFormat(ResultFormatType.JSON)
            .result("benchmark-result/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".json")
```

Here's the output:

```json
[
    {
        "jmhVersion" : "1.36",
        "benchmark" : "",
        "mode" : "avgt",
        "threads" : 1,
        "forks" : 1,
        "jvm" : "",
        "jvmArgs" : [
            "-Xms2G",
            "-Xmx2G"
        ],
        "jdkVersion" : "",
        "vmName" : "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM",
        "vmVersion" : "",
        "warmupIterations" : 5,
        "warmupTime" : "10 s",
        "warmupBatchSize" : 1,
        "measurementIterations" : 5,
        "measurementTime" : "10 s",
        "measurementBatchSize" : 1,
        "params" : {
            "orientdbUrl" : "remote:localhost:2424/database"
        },
        "primaryMetric" : {
            "score" : 86.41678545945095,
            "scoreError" : 9.76599990211842,
            "scoreConfidence" : [
                76.65078555733253,
                96.18278536156937
            ],
            "scorePercentiles" : {
                "0.0" : 82.68515289256199,
                "50.0" : 87.28553391304348,
                "90.0" : 89.14723716814159,
                "95.0" : 89.14723716814159,
                "99.0" : 89.14723716814159,
                "99.9" : 89.14723716814159,
                "99.99" : 89.14723716814159,
                "99.999" : 89.14723716814159,
                "99.9999" : 89.14723716814159,
                "100.0" : 89.14723716814159
            },
            "scoreUnit" : "ms/op",
            "rawData" : [
                [
                    82.68515289256199,
                    89.14723716814159,
                    87.82189739130435,
                    85.14410593220339,
                    87.28553391304348
                ]
            ]
        },
        "secondaryMetrics" : {
        }
    }
]
```